# Selecting Values in a csv file using pandas and compute them

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to coding and need, for a project, to select values in a csv file using pandas and to compute those values. What i want is to select two column and multiple rows to compute them, for example, multiply a column by another column. I succeed to select values but not to compute them, here is what i have.

```
import pandas as pd`
data = pd.read_csv("csvfilet.csv", delimiter=";", decimal=",")
print(data.iloc[57:67, 3])
print(data.iloc[57:67, 7])
data.iloc[57:68, 3] = data.iloc[57:68, 3]*data.iloc[57:68, 7]
print(data.iloc[57:68, 3])
```

It firstly print me correctly the two columns i want with the data.iloc(), but it seems like i can't do this it shows me:

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>   so i tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("csvfilet.csv", delimiter=";", decimal=",")
print(data.iloc[57:67, 3])
print(data.iloc[57:67, 7])
x=data.iloc[57:68, 7:8]
y=data.iloc[57:68, 3:4]
z=x*y
print(z)
```

and it gives me the two columns where the values are replaced by NaN. 
Is there a way to compute values that we select (by row and columns) directly in a csv file?

*Edit: The csv file where i need to extract values looks like this:

```
[Name];[Switching (us)];[Memory (byte)];;;;;;;;;
S1;20,5;;;;;;;;;;
S3;;256;;;;;;;;;
[Name];[Priority];[ArrivalType];[MinDistance (ms)];[MaxDistance (ms)];[SizeType];[Min Size (byte)];[MaxSize (byte)];[BurstSize];[Sender];[Receiver];[Latency (ms)]
FL_1;1;Periodic;5;;ETHERNET_FRAME_SIZE;;100;;Node4;Node6;2
FL_2;1;Periodic;2;;ETHERNET_FRAME_SIZE;;20;;Node3;Node4;1,5
```

and for example i will need to select the '5' right to FL_1 and to multiply it by the '100' on the same row.

Comment: Just convert them to numeric ..

Comment: Can you add the list of column types? Add the output of `data.dtypes`

Comment: In the first attempt, I don't understand - are you really trying to replace column 3 with column 3 * column 7? data[z] = data[x] * data[y] is what you're looking for, I believe.

Comment: Yes i tried to replace column 3 with column 3 * column 7, thanks for the answers, going to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
data.iloc[57:68, 3] = (data.iloc[57:68, 3].astype(int).values 
                      * data.iloc[57:68, 7].astype(int).values)
```

Convert your range from `iloc` to type `int` and multiply the values.

**Update**

So the main issue here is that you were reading your file wrongly, from your sample text, there are 2 different data structures. In the code below I used `skiprows` to remove the data you do not need.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("csvfilet.csv", delimiter=";", decimal=",", skiprows = 3)
print(data.iloc[0, 3])
print(data.iloc[0, 7])

#create a new series in your frame
data['NewMinDistance'] = data['[MinDistance (ms)]'].astype(int) * data['[MaxSize (byte)]'].astype(int)
data[['[Name]','[MinDistance (ms)]','[MaxSize (byte)]','NewMinDistance']]

#or with your earlier method, directly assign it to a dataframe position
data.iloc[0, 3] =   (data.iloc[0, 3].astype(int) * data.iloc[0, 7].astype(int))
```

Your example earlier uses positional assignment where you directly assigned new values to your data frame using `iloc`. Depending on your requirements, my answer above also includes creating a new column with the values you need, rather that assigning it to a current value in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i got another problem, i just had the error "could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (11)" and "could not convert string to float: '3,25'", I changed .astype(int) by .astype(float) but i have the same error.

Comment: Can you post the contents of you dataframe? There can be multiple reasons those errors occur and it is gonna be too broad to troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there a way to send a csv file on the post? There is a lot of informations in the file.

Comment: It is always a better practice to share a small snippet that allows people to recreate your problem. Rather than dumping the whole lot. You can manually build your sample dataframe for an example.

Comment: I tried with building the dataframe manually, and it is working, but i need to directly select values on the csv file and compute them, but i'll give an example of what the dataframe looks like (on a .txt) on the post.

Comment: Updated my answer. I also see you are relatively new here, if any of the answers has solved your question, you can close the question by selecting an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time to help me, but it still don't work with my csv, i tried the second answer you gave only with the example i gave you and it worked, but when i tried to redo the program with the original csv file, it just don't work because "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'" and i don't understand why with more Dataframe it doesn't work.

Comment: How about now, it means that in your csv there are values which are not integer format. As you have mentioned, the answers can only be for the examples you have provided and there is no way to assume what we do not know.

Comment: If you want the full csv i can send you it by mail, but still i don't understand the problem i have, for the original csv, it correctly print me 5 and 100, but in the step to multiply 5 by 100, it don't work and gives the error i mentioned, sorry, it looks strange to me.

Comment: Sorry, if you find any answers that solved your described question, it will be great if you can close the question by checking the answer checkbox. Else, if you have another question other than what you described, feel free to post a different question. Constant back and forths between updated questions and answers can confuse other viewers.